# Using the correct word against collaboration and Collaborative

Tags: verbs

To say as a third person that [I believe in collaborative work]
what is the correct usage

> beliefs on collaborative work
>   or
>   believe on collaborations
>   or
>   beliefs on collaborations
>   or
>   believe on collaborative work

Prefer it with a detail explanations

Comment: The first sentence of the question states it correctly, "I believe in collaborative work".  You could also say, "I believe in collaboration."  It isn't clear how or why you changed that in your four examples, but "on" is incorrect, the plural noun "beliefs" is incorrect, and the plural "collaborations" isn't necessary.  And it isn't clear how the four examples are supposed to relate to third person.  Can you elaborate on your thinking?

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

You are confusing the noun "belief" with the verb "believe". For more information on this, see this related question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/74194/16318). You also are lacking a subject, so that additionally makes none of the choices correct either.

The correct form is

> He/she believes in collaborative work.
>   They believe in collaborative work. (non-gendered singular they)

But this has nothing to do with "collaborative work", so perhaps I'm not understanding your question fully?

Now, I might say:

> Her beliefs on collaborative work are irrelevant to this discussion.

In this case, "beliefs" is a noun, not a verb but you need more in the sentence because without it, all you have is a subject.

Comment: Could I say like this "A strong believer in collaborative work" or is it "A Strong believer in collaborations and work ethic". Which one is better?

Comment: Neither of those examples are sentences. As phrases they are both fine.